# Data not being saved in Database due to limited size of the field

Tags: java, sql, oracle

There is a column `message` in the database table `fsr_system_log` for the schema `fsr_appl`. This table is supposed to store the system log message. The size of the column is 255 and the datatype is `varchar2`. The logic implemented for saving message whose size is greater than 255 characters is :

```
public void saveSystemLog(SystemLogRequest systemLog){
    User user = systemLog.getUser();
    String system = systemLog.getSystem();
    Log log = systemLog.getSystemLog();

    try {
        initializeDelegate();
        delegate.beginTransaction();

        LogEntry[] logEntries = log.getItemArray();
        for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
            // Save each entry
            ParamVector<Object> params = new ParamVector<Object>();

            //Check if message is greater than 255 characters
            String message = logEntry.getMsg();
            notifier.debug("Log Message is : " + message);
            if(message.length()>255){
                message = message.substring(0,255);
                notifier().debug("Message string greater than 255 characters : " + message);
            }
            params.add(message, 255, false);
}
```

But despite implementing the code, I face the following error :

> Failed to save system log due to SQL error: ORA-12899: value too large for column "FSR_APPL". "FSR_SYSTEM_LOG". "MESSAGE" (actual: 257,
>   maximum: 255)

A sample log being used is :

```
<xbe:systemLogRequest xmlns:xbe="http://tdc.dk/fsr/common/xbean">
<user>
    <userNumber>a62267</userNumber>
</user>
<system>Client</system>
<systemLog>
    <item>
        <timestamp>2011-10-27T17:03:08.404+02:00</timestamp>
        <type>Info</type>
        <msg><![CDATA[<html><center>Din registrering er nu sendt<br><br>Tak for indmeldingen</center></html>]]></msg>
    </item>
    <item>
        <timestamp>2011-10-27T17:03:13.701+02:00</timestamp>
        <type>Info</type>
        <msg><![CDATA[<html><center>Din registrering er nu sendt<br><br>Tak for indmeldingen</center></html>]]></msg>
    </item>
    <item>
        <timestamp>2011-10-28T12:45:47.801+02:00</timestamp>
        <type>Info</type>
        <msg><![CDATA[<html><center>Din registrering er nu sendt<br><br>Tak for indmeldingen</center></html>]]></msg>
    </item>
    <item>
        <timestamp>2011-10-28T12:45:57.926+02:00</timestamp>
        <type>Info</type>
        <msg>Afsluttet uden at gemme fejlregistering</msg>
    </item>
</systemLog>
</xbe:systemLogRequest>
```

Please help!

**Note :** The error thrown is for certain system log messages only. And the actual value is always a constant 257 when this error is being thrown.

Comment: Are you using Java?  It looks like you are, but it could be another language.  This may be a Java issue.  There may be non-ASCII characters which are represented in UTF-8 as multibyte characters.  If so, doing a substring to 255 characters will be more than 255 bytes.  Call getBytes on the substring result, and get the size of the byte array.

Comment: @MarlinPierce Yes..I am using JAVA. If using substring won't help, then what alternative do we have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your field type to CLOB, BLOB, or XMLType.  Looking up Oracle data types, VARCHAR2 seems to also work on bytes.

You might, understandably, not want to change your field type, in which case, replace

```
if(message.length()>255){
  message = message.substring(0,255);
  notifier().debug("Message string greater than 255 characters : " + message);
}
```

with

```
pos = 255
while (message.getBytes().size() > 255) {
  message = message.substring(0,pos--);
}
```

Comment: why am I supposed to use while loop?wouldn't simply using "if" condition work fine?

Comment: Well, right now you have exactly one multibyte character, and the size is consistently 257.  But what if later you have two multibyte characters?  Also, unless the multibyte character is the last character, you may have to trim off two single byte characters to go from length 257 to 255.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have some characters that are represented with more than one byte.

In Java you get the length of the String in *characters* whereas Oracle apparently checks the *byte* limit due to the way the column was defined.

Check out the definition of your table, most probably the column is defined with default character semantics - which is byte (but depends on your Oracle installation), so it defaults to `VARCHAR2(255 Byte)`

If you redefine the column as `VARCHAR2(255 Char)` things should be fine.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE FSR_SYSTEM_LOG
(
   ...
   MESSAGE  VARCHAR2(255 Char),
   ...
);
```

To me it seems rather strange to store an XML in such a (length) limited column. Can you make sure your XML is **never** longer than 255 characters? Why don't you store the message as a `CLOB`?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I suspect an encoding issue...

Java uses unicode : a **character** in unicode may cost one to *many* byte(s)...
A java string's length may be 1 but when marshalled on storage, it can take 2 bytes, 4bytes...

To check bytes length, maybe you should try:

```
if(message.getBytes("US-ASCII").length()>255){
```

What is the encoding of your Oracle DB ?

Another possible issue is the class that writes to the DB adds a CR/LF(0D0A) to the msg parameter or something else...